# Trying to pass a number of bytes to read() via raw_input

Tags: python, function, methods, terminology

I'm doing some extra credit for "Zed Shaw's Learn Python The Hard Way;" the "extra credit" for exercise 15 tells you to read through pydoc file to find other things I could do files. I was interested in figuring out how to have the terminal print out a certain number of bytes of a text file using "read()". I can hard code in the argument for how many bytes to read, but I hit a wall when trying to prompt the user to define the number of bytes.

Here's the script as I have it so far:

```
    from sys import argv

    script, filename = argv

    txt = open(filename)

    print "Here's 24 bytes of your file %r:" % filename

    print txt.read(24)

    print """What about an arbitrary, not hard-coded number of bytes? Enter the number
    of bytes you want read out of the txt file at this prompt, as an integer:"""

    how_far = raw_input("> ")

    print txt.read(how_far2) # this format makes sense in my head but obviously isn't the done thing.
```

terminal spits out the error:

```
"NameError: name 'how_far2' is not defined"
```

**How do I prompt the user of the script to type in a number of bytes, and have the script read out that number of bytes?**

BONUS QUESTIONS:

1. What is the actual-factual term for what I'm doing trying to do here? Pass a variable to a method? Pass a variable to a function?
2. Is the number of bytes an *argument* of read? Is that the correct term?
3. More generally, what's a good place to get a vocabulary list of python terms? Any other books Stack Overflow would recommend, or some in online documentation somewhere? Really looking for a no assumptions, no prior knowledge, "explain it to me like I'm five" level of granularity... a half hour of web-searching hasn't helped too much. I've not found terminology really collected together into any one place online despite a good amount of effort searching the web.

Comment: you might want to check out [the official python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/)

Comment: The most obvious place to get a "vocabulary list of python terms" is the [Python Language Reference](http://docs.python.org/reference/), which is part of the standard set of docs. It's a fairly technical document but it at least provides the terminology used; you can supplement this with the [Standard Library](http://docs.python.org/library/) documentation, which explains everything at a higher level.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is because you have used `how_far` in one place and `how_far2` in the other.

You'll also need to convert `how_far` to an `int` before passing it to read - using `int(how_far)` for example

You will find it can be called passing a variable, parameter or argument. These are not Python terms, they are general programming terms

Comment: That explains the `NameError`, but even if OP uses `how_far` in both places, there will still be an error.

Comment: @mgilson, yes, but when you are learning, it's usually best to fix the error Python is complaining about. The next error would be `TypeError: an integer is required` for the `read()`

Answer (score 0):

`raw_input` returns a string.  `file.read` expects an integer -- likely you just need to convert the output from `raw_input` into an integer before you use it.